# Compressing Function.prototype.bind into 140 characters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is the bind polyfill function from MDN:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
        // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
        // internal IsCallable function
        throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP = function() {},
        fBound = function() {
            return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP ? this : oThis,
                aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    if (this.prototype) {
        // Function.prototype doesn't have a prototype property
        fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    }
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
};
```

I wanted to compress this into 140 characters or less using ES2015 syntax.

Does the following achieve the same goal (albeit not a method on `Function.prototype`)?

```
var bind=(f,t,...a)=>{
 function g(...b){
   return f.call(this instanceof g?this:t,...a,...b)
 }
 g.prototype=Object.create(f.prototype||{});
 return g
}
```

I am particularly interested in whether the `instanceof` check is equivalent.

Edit: `g` converted to non-arrow function (which breaks the character limit by one character if whitespace is removed)

Comment: Won't `this` have the wrong value if you're using an arrow function?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right.

Answer (score 0):

your ES6 syntax is much nicer

**Binding Shim Condensed its 161**

```
var bound1 = myFunction.bind(arg1, arg2, arg3);

Function.prototype.bind=function(d){
     var s=Array.prototype.splice,
         a=s.call(arguments,1),
         c=this;

     return function(){
         return c.apply(d,a.concat(s.call(arguments,0)))
     }
 }
```

**Binding Utility Function 103**

```
var bound2 = bind(myFunction, [arg1, arg2, arg3]);

function bind(f,a) {
     return function(){
         return f.call(a.concat(Array.prototype.splice.all(arguments,0)));
     }
}
```

Comment: 285 according to the comment on the page you linked.

Comment: Why would you post it without counting?